# Error connecting to MySQL at 127.0.0.1 from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

This is the file that I use to connect a local mysql database.

```
<?php
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'richard77';
$dbpass = '************';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
        or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'memcache';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

**richard77** is my Ubuntu username with **sudo privileges**. the above password is the same password I enter when using sudo commands.

I keep getting the same error: `Error connecting to mysql`. I've tried several combinations: For `$dbhost`: `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`, and for `$dbuser`: `richard77`, `richard77--VirtualBox`, and `richard77@richard77--VirtualBox`.

I don't even know anymore which part of my connection string is failing. Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: MySQL does not normally use system passwords (which is what you would use for `sudo`) and is not aware of the Linux system's users. You need to create the user in the MySQL server before you can connect to it. If you connect on the command line with the MySQL root user password, you must then grant privileges for your user `richard77`.

Comment: See [adding user accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Side note: `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. Don't use them for new code. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said, you need an own user account in MySQL. You can create one, using the MySQL root account (which is not the system root!) as follows:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secure_password';"
```

This will create the user, set a password, and grant the user all privileges on the database you want him to manage.

Note: It is important that you write `dbname.*` and `username@localhost`. Don't just write `dbname` or `username`.

If you don't have the MySQL root password, and you are on a Debian based system (which Ubuntu is), you can use the `debian-sys-maint` account and the password you find in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p -e "GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secure_password';"
```

Comment: In my case, it should be something like `mysql -u root -p -e "GRANT ALL ON memcache.* TO  richard77@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secure_password';`